# Natural log of a negative number

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

My teacher told me that the natural logarithm of a negative number does not exist,
but

$$\ln(-1)=\ln (e^{i\pi})=i\pi$$

So, is it logical to have the natural logarithm of a negative number?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  The logarithm of a negative number does not exist in the context of real numbers, though any odd integer multiple of $i\pi$ is a logarithm of $-1$

Comment: Also, $-1=\mathrm{e}^{3 \mathrm{i} \pi}$. Therefore, $\ln(-1) = 3\mathrm{i} \pi$.

Comment: Yes, just like we can extend the real map $x\to e^x$ to a complex map $z\to e^z$ which is usually defined by the power series of $e^x$ replaced by a complex variable $z$, we can define a complex logarithm $z\to\log(z)$ from $\Bbb C^\times\to\Bbb C$ as being a partial inverse to the complex exponentiation map; in general, it is a multi-valued function because $e^{iz}=e^{2ni\pi+iz}$ and we take the principal branch $n=0$ when talking about complex logarithm; for more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Complex_plane

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Context is important here. *In the context of real numbers*, negative numbers have no logarithms (and neither does $0$) because $\log(x)$ is a number $y$ such that $e^y=x$ and $e^y$ is always greater than $0$.

On the other hand, *in the context of complex numbers*, every complex number other than $0$ has logarithms. In fact, any such complex number has infinitely many logarithms! You are right when you claim that $i\pi$ is **a** logarithm of $-1$. However, *every* complex number of the form $\pi i+2\pi in$ (with $n\in\Bbb Z)$ is *also* a logarithm of $-1$, since$$e^{\pi i+2n\pi i}=e^{\pi i}e^{2\pi in}=(-1)\times1=-1.$$

Comment: Even in the context of complex numbers, $0\in\Bbb C$ doesn't have a logarithm. We cannot define $\log(0)$ since the complex exponentiation $z\mapsto e^z$ doesn't map any element of $\Bbb C$ to $0$

Comment: Also, if the logarithm is a function, it means it's a function with infinitely values, which causes also some trouble (among others) with identities like $\ln(xy)=\ln x+\ln y$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut In the context of complex numbers, I did *not* claim that $\log$ is a function.

Comment: Right. It's a comment for the OP to consider the problems that are going to arise, and that would require much theory (up to [Riemann surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface)) to deal with correctly. I know *you* are aware of that.

Comment: Would it make sense then to write $i\theta \in \log(-1)$?

Comment: @Joe It depends. What is $\theta$?

Comment: I meant $i\pi$, sorry. Basically, I’m asking how common it is to define $\log$ as a multifunction in the complex plane (as opposed to a single valued function defined using branch cuts).

Comment: It is not much common. It is more common to deal with branches of the logarithm. For instance, the main branch of the logarihtm is the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}\operatorname{Log}\colon&\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\log|z|+\operatorname{arg}(z)i,\end{array}$$where $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ is the only argument of $z$ which belongs to $(-\pi,\pi)$. It turns out that it is a continuous (and even an analytic) function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Right, so this is the principal branch of the logarithm. So if $z=re^{i \theta}$, then $\operatorname{Log}(z) = \ln(r) + i\theta$. Under your definition, $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is undefined for negative $z$. If we define $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ as $\ln(r) + i\pi$ for negative $z$, then do we lose these nice continuous and analytic properties?

Comment: @Joe Yes, we do.

Answer (score 5):

$\log(-1)=i\pi$ is the principal value of the logarithm of $-1$. In general: the principal value of $\log re^{i\theta}$ is $\log r+i\theta$ where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$, and adding integer multiples of $2i\pi$ produces all other possible logarithms.

Your teacher was correct... but only in the fully real setting.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different point of view by Felix Klein, Elementary Mathematics from an advanced standpoint:

[image]